# How to fetch data correctly in a react/redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

I've seen this question repeated a lot of times, but I'm trying to develop a react/redux app and every time i tried to fetch data before the page is loaded i got a lot of problems.
I feel the problem is the async calls, looks that sometimes when i use the data result of the data fetch, the store hasn't upload yet, so i try to access to undefined variables and i get error.

I've tried to use `componentDidMount()` and from inside the method trigger an action that fetch the data and actualize the store state for me . I also tried to use `componentDidMount()` and then `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to use the data when i cannot directly use it in the html.

So the problem is that sometimes, not always, the data i want to fetch is already undefined when i use it. Is there a way to avoid that? And How is the correct way to fetch data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using componentWillMount? Everything you put inside componentWillMount will execute before your application gets rendered, unlike componentDidMount where first you get your application rendered, then it executes everything you put inside.

Also, have you every looked at hooks and useEffect function? Try to research hooks cause it will solve a lot of boilerplate with standard lifecycle functions.

Comment: isn't componentWillMount deprecated? And yes, iv'e heard about hooks, but I will definitely read more about it.

Comment: Yes it is deprecated, sorry. You can still do conditional rendering. You can wrap everything inside return function to be rendered when you get something from fetch. Meanwhile you can do some loading animation, so the user can be sure something is going on and he needs to wait. But look at hooks. They are easy to learn and understand and useEffect hook will solve your problem.

Comment: no problem with `componentDidMount`. Did you use `react-redux` to map your state value to component's props.

Comment: He don't even have to use Redux for it. ContextAPI is very good and it even have its hook. Since he is going to learn hooks, it would be good to take the best out of them.